# why does gdb print std::string in such a confusing way?

Tags: gdb

I want to read out the content of an std::string while debugging, but the output is rather inconclusive

```
(gdb) p returnTypeStr
$2 = {static npos = 18446744073709551615, _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_p = 0x48 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x48>}, _M_string_length = 93825009948928, {_M_local_buf = "\000\004bVUU\000\000@\000\000\000\000\000\000", _M_allocated_capacity = 93825009845248}}
```

why is that? the program works perfectly if I print the string within the code itself

Comment: Do you have [pretty printers](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport) enabled?

Comment: Was `returnTypeStr` string initialized at the time you tried to print it? Try to step to the next source line with `next` and print string again.

Comment: yes it was and no I dont have pretty printin on

Comment: could you also provide the gdb version you're using. But one thing you should know is, std::string is not an primitive data types, it's a class.